# Substring of paths, can't find second occurrence of \\

Tags: java

I have a string

```
"H:\\DVR mo\\Whats app video\\Sent\\VID-20170430-WA0006.mp4"
```

I wanted to know **how many slashes** are there in the string and I have found it with the help of the `String#charAt` function.

Now, I know there are `4` slashes in the above string. I want to select the string **from index zero to second occurrence of slash**. So the desired result would be:

```
"H:\\DVR mo"
```

But I don't know how to find the index of the second occurrence.

Comment: You probably should **parse** the URL as URL and not as `String`. For example as `Path`. Then such stuff gets very easy. Do `Paths.get(...)` and then use the methods of the `Path` class to navigate around. If you really want to you can use `input.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex);` with the indices you have found in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

A modular, platform independent solution:

```
String result = StreamSupport.stream(Paths.get(input).spliterator(), false)
    .skip(numberOfSubPath - 1)
    .findFirst()
    .map(Path::toString)
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

A compact but non-flexible solution:

```
String result = Pattern.compile("\\").splitAsStream(input)
    .limit(numberOfSubPath)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\\"));
```

For your example, set the variables to:

```
String input = "H:\\DVR mo\\Whats app video\\Sent\\VID-20170430-WA0006.mp4";
int numberOfSubPath = 2;
```

---

### Using `Path`

If your strings always represent valid file system paths you should consider **parsing** your input as `Path` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)). Therefore, use the `Paths#get` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)).

The `Path` class offers various methods to navigate on the given path, for example `getRoot` or `getParent`. Since we want to create a `Path` from the first to the second file element we will use `Path#iterator` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#iterator--)):

```
String input = "H:\\DVR mo\\Whats app video\\Sent\\VID-20170430-WA0006.mp4";
int numberOfSubPath = 2;

Path path = Paths.get(input);
Iterator<Path> subPaths = path.iterator();
Path result = null;

// Iterate to the desired subpath
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubPath; i++) {
    // If there is no such subpath
    if (!subPaths.hasNext()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input does not have a subpath of number"
            + numberOfSubPath);
    }

    // Assign the current subpath as possible result
    result = subPaths.next();
}
// The variable 'result' now holds the desired subpath

System.out.println(result);
```

A more compact `Stream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)) approach:

```
Path path = Paths.get(input);
String result = StreamSupport.stream(path.spliterator(), false)  // Stream<Path>
    .skip(numberOfSubPath - 1)  // Skip all elements before desired path
    .findFirst()                // Optional<Path>
    .map(Path::toString)        // Optional<String>
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);  // The subpath as String or exception
```

---

### Using `String`

If you, for some reason, want to use `String`s for this task, I would recommend using the `String#indexOf` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)) method instead of `String#charAt` to find the index of the second `\\` occurrence. After that use `String#substring` to extract that part ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)).

```
int lastIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubPath; i++) {
    // Find the next occurrence starting from 'lastIndex'
    lastIndex = input.indexOf("\\", lastIndex);

    // There is no next occurrence
    if (lastIndex == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input does not have a subpath of number"
            + numberOfSubPath);
    }
}

// Extract the text from the beginning to 'lastIndex'
String result = input.substring(0, lastIndex);
```

Alternatively you can use the `String#split` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)) method which essentially does the same under the hood:

```
// Split the input on each '\\', limit the results
String[] parts = input.split("\\", numberOfSubPath + 1);

// Build the result by concatenating the parts (and adding '\\' again)
StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner("\\");
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubPath; i++) {
    result.add(parts[i]);
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

The same using `Stream`s:

```
String result = Pattern.compile("\\").splitAsStream(input)
    .limit(numberOfSubPath)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work on strings you explicitly know are strings, probably the best way is to use Path class as other people suggested.

Otherwise, you always have the String.split way. Of course the code I wrote is missing all the checking parts.

```
String s = "H:\\DVR mo\\Whats app video\\Sent\\VID-20170430-WA0006.mp4";
String[] array = s.split("\\");
String result = array[0]+"\\"+array[1];
```

Comment: You need to double-slash the url when creating from inside java.

Comment: Creating a `Path` and extracting information makes much sense than splitting it. Also consider adding more information in your answer because it is currently useless for a new comer.

Comment: thanks both Zabuza and @Aniket Sahrawat for your comments. Though, Anniket, I don't think that he is explicitly asking this to work on strings representing paths, am I wrong?

Comment: yes...my need is to get the substring of zero to second slash.. In this case split may not work....

Comment: @balsick i can use split but in a loop i cannot add elements of array as String result = array[0]+"\\"+array[1];